# Is Milo Murphy actually super lucky?

Tags: milo-murphys-law

When watching Milo Murphy's Law, especially the later episodes, you'll notice that Milo Murphy actaully seems to be very lucky, not unlucly.

Consider [Morgan Lucchi's list:](http://milomurphyslaw.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:1297)

> I wanted to talk about something which I think everyone noticed:
>
> Is Milo REALLY unlucky as they say?
>
> Ok, surely he has to, because of the whole mechanic of the show, but he had some very lucky moments! Anyway... it looks like Milo doesn't have to be exactly unlucky. Check this
>
> 1) They broke 10135.05 eggs in 17 hours, he caused an explosion of an entire truck full of eggs. Anyway he didn't break the egg into his pocket, it survived for 1 or 2 days intact inside his pocket!
>
> 2) When they got lost underground, Diogee found them.
>
> 3) Even though their part of the metro crashed everywhere, it still fell "on its feet" (metaphorically talking) every time.
>
> 4) Just saying "We really need to go to school" made a pair of aliens who wanted to... open their bodies, I guess, to let them go. They even teleported Milo and Zack to school!
>
> 5) Despite being splatted under rocks he had no problems but a broken thumb.
>
> UPDATE 1: (thanks to Paige EM for noticing these)
>
> 6) Receving a fully-stocked backpack from a former baby-sitter.
>
> 7) A bee hive from Coyotye Woods didn't land by Milo and Zack. (This led to a worse consequence so... some of you may complain about how "lucky" was this moment)
>
> 8) It looks like in "The Note" Milo's not signed papers stay where they are supposed to stay, although they could fly away like the signed one.
>
> 9) Milo, Zack, and Melissa landing in Cavendish and Dakota's car after they fell through a hot air baloon basket.
>
> UPDATE 2: (I'm back with some more lucky moments!)
>
> 10) The ostrich he was riding at the zoo fell right on his feet, instead of falling upside down therefore breaking Milo's neck. (We're going to the Zoo)
>
> 11) Milo's and Dakota's heads passed very near each other at high speed withouth hitting and therefore dying.
>
> 12) They fell on their feet on the drainage pipe instead of falling upside down right in front of it, having no chance to avoid being splatted. (Going the extra Milo)
>
> 13) In "The Note", the note often fells in places it can be seen directly.
>
> Add every lucky situation you saw, if you want. Anyway, do not add those moments when they solve some situation using their ability, because that's not luck, that's smartness.

So considering the main premise of the show is Milo's unluckiness, why does Milo seem to be so lucky? Has any of the creators/writers addressed this? or or is it possible we completely misunderstand Murphy's law?

(The same author has a take on this [here](http://milomurphyslaw.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:4261), but I don't know if it's supported by canon.)

Comment: Murphy's law isn't about luck. It's simply "anything that can go wrong will go wrong". And of course if they all died then that would be an end to the series, and not very entertaining.

Comment: I think that it's a bit like saying "wow, Person N has had five different cancers and survived them all.  He/she is so lucky!"  In a way it's true, but I feel like someone who had zero cancers is still luckier by far.

Comment: @TheAsh This is like a writing style in novel. "Protagonist A want to fail but he keep success". This style keep audience feel interesting in what happen next more than "Protagonist A want to success and he keep success".

Answer (score 2):

Milo's talent for survival lies not in luck, but in his preparedness.  Thanks to his backpack, he carries with him just about anything needed to survive any scenario. Combined with years of experience, he's able to think on his feet and come up with a strategy for making it out relatively unscathed of the calamities that happen about him.

He's described a jinx in the show (particularly in the first episode) but he doesn't quite fit the traditional forms of a jinx we see in entertainment. Usually, things happen ONLY to a jinx, or in the inverse, happen to all AROUND them, leaving the jinx unscathed. His father seems more an example of the latter - his calamities seem to happen around him, but unlike Milo, seem to be fixed by the people around him, and much less with his assistance.

Milo and his father also don't suffer from the depression seen in many literary jinxes. Likely it's because of that ability to find a way to make it out of the scenarios with minimal harm. Milo sees his life as exciting, and not harrowing. He takes what happens to and around him and turns it into a positive.